# controllerFor not properly setting the controller in ember.js

Tags: controller, ember.js, router

I have the following router:

```
Whistlr.OrganizationsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    Whistlr.Organization.createRecord()
  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    @controllerFor('organization').set('content', model)
```

This gets invoked in the new organization form, which has several inputs with bindings like:

```
Em.TextField valueBinding="name"
```

When I enter data into any of these inputs, I get this error message:

```
Cannot delegate set('name', C) to the 'content' property of object proxy <Whistlr.OrganizationsNewController:ember519>: its 'content' is undefined.
```

Which tells me that the controller isn't being properly set by the router. Why is that happening?

Comment: Is the controller an Ember.ObjectController?

Comment: It is an Ember.OjbectController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is you are setting the model to the `Whistlr.OrganizationsController`, where as the `controller` for the `Whistlr.OrganizationsNewRoute` will be `Whistlr.OrganizationsNewController` whose content is not set as you've overridden the `setupController` of `Whistlr.OrganizationsNewRoute`.

If you want the `Whistlr.OrganizationsNewRoute` to have `Whistlr.OrganizationsController` as the default controller, you can do so by

```
Whistlr.OrganizationsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        controllerName: 'organization'
});
```

which will set the `Whistlr.OrganizationsController` as the default controller for your `Whistlr.OrganizationsController`, by which you may not need to override the `setupController` also. But this is available in master only.

If you are using a RC build <= 1.0.0.RC6, you've to do so by mentioning the controller in `renderTemplate` of `Whistlr.OrganizationsNewRoute`.

```
    Whistlr.OrganizationsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
           setupController: function(controller,model) {
                 this.controllerFor('organization').set('content', model)
           },
           renderTemplate: function(){
                  this.render({ controller: 'organization' });
           }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. This works perfectly, at least when adding `renderTemplate`. Curiously, I'm using ember-source rc6.4, but I continue to get the error unless I add `renderTemplate`.

Answer (score 0):

The value returned from your model hook will be assigned to the model property.In  setupController model will be undefined if u do not return anything.

model: ->
 return Whistlr.Organization.createRecord()

Comment: One of the perks of using coffeescript is that it automatically returns the last line. Even manually entering the `return` doesn't resolve the problem. Thanks for the suggestion, though!